# No sound on detected headphones (arch)

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, audio

alsamixer and pavucontrol shows everything is detected and unmuted. The speaker on my Laptop are working, only the headphones are detected and on mute or unmute I hear a short crack and nothing happens. Hardware sounds (beep) are possible. Sound card is Intel hda.

Comment: Fixed after kernel update.